# Icons in top bar of Ubuntu 22.04 are out of the screen due to many installed extensions

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar

I think I installed way too many GNOME extensions and now my top bar icons are out of my screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way to fix/organize this without disabling my GNOME extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only so much can fit. Rationalize. Install only these extensions that really enhance your work flow. Install extensions in a way that fits your title bar.